# Why exclude the constant sequence from this definition

Tags: real-analysis, definition

As in the title: I am interested in why it is necessary to exclude the constant sequence from the following definition of a functional limit:

[image]

Note the $0 < |x-c|$. Why would the definition break down if only $|x-c|<y\delta$ was required?

Comment: It wouldn't break down, it would lead to another concept of limit in the case where $c$ is in the domain of $f$. If you just demand $\lvert x-c\rvert < \delta$ and $x\in A$, the limit would exist if and only if $f$ is continuous in $c$.

Comment: @DanielFischer But with this definition $c$ can also be in the domain of $f$. And demanding $|x-c|<\delta$ it could be outside the domain of $f$. Does the definition with $|x-c|<\delta$ imply the definition with $0<|x-c|<\delta$?

Comment: No. In the case $c\notin A$, the $x\in A$ implies $\lvert x-c\rvert > 0$, and both definitions agree. For $c\in A$, the two definitions define a different concept of limit. The one with $0 < \lvert x-c\rvert < \delta$ explicitly leaves $f(c)$ out of consideration, so $f(x) = 0$, if $x\neq 0$, and $f(0) = 1$ has a limit at $0$ in that definition. If only $\lvert x-c\rvert <\delta$ (and $x\in A$) is demanded, $f(c)$ is included in the consideration, and hence the only possible value of the limit. Either definition is in some cases more convenient than the other, but it's always just a small

Comment: modification to formulate the theorems in terms of the other definition. The most important applications of the concept are when $c\notin A$, and then the two definitions agree anyway.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for your explanation, I understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you allow for the constant sequence, then the existence of the limit implies the continuity of $f$ at $c$ and $L = f(c)$. Using the above definition, you can also handle discontinuous functions.

**Edit:** As mentioned by Daniel Fischer above, it would be even equivalent to the continuity of $f$.